# Avoid default results in Search Result Web Part

Tags: search, search-results, ootb

I have used Search Box and Search Result web part on my `Home.aspx` page.

[image]

I have added query text in search result web part, it's working fine and shows results.

But I want to hide the default result.

I want to show result only when user enter text in Search Box web part.

How can this be done?

I had tried this [Article](https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/sharepoint2013-avoid-default-results-in-search-result-and-content-search-web-part-with-search-box/), but it will redirect to `osssearchresults.aspx` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `\\{searchboxquery?}` to your Search Results Web Parts content source should work. If you are redirected to `osssearchresults.aspx` it sounds like you have changed the settings on the Search Box Web Part, make sure the setting; `Send queries to other Web Parts on this page` is checked, and your Search Result Web Part is marked as retriever.

Comment: Anders.! you are right  ,I have selected option :send query to custom result page URL instead of  send queries to other webpart on this page.
not it's worked for me.

Comment: it's not working for me' one file found. maybe because `'\\'` is text in tha file.
 but more than 2 `'\\'` work like this: `'\\\\'`

Answer (score 0):

wrap your query with `{?...}`
`{?{searchBoxQuery} path:"<your path>" ContentTypeId:<any content type> }`

see also https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/09/customizing-the-search-control-display-template/